# How to highlight parent item when child item is selected

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm very new to javascript and jQuery and I can't seem to figure this out on my own.

This code was in a blank wordpress "starter" template and can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/AyStc/13/

(note: I added those obnoxious colors to contrast the white background. They aren't the colors on the site!)

I'm having trouble figuring out these 2 things:

1. Make it so the background of the parent items stay blue when the cursor moves to a child item below them.
2. When someone clicks on a child item and goes to that page, the parent item text stays highlighted to indicate which section of the site the user is on.

I've been reading about .closest() in jQuery, but I can't seem to make it work like this.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to find the parent, then get the children and then filter out the one you need. Something like:

```
$("#navi ul.menu li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul.sub-menu')
        .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "show", "opacity": "show" }, 500 ).parent().children('a:first').css('background-color','blue');
}, function(){
    $(this).find('ul.sub-menu')
        .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "hide", "opacity": "hide" }, 200 ).parent().children('a:first').css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

Or, .prev('a') does the same thing, if you know the Parent X always precedes the submenu.

Comment: The only thing left is the highlighting of the parent item when the child page is selected. I've added this line

$("ul.sub-menu").closest("ul.menu li a").addClass("shizzle");

but with tinkering I'm only able to get the background to change, not the text inside it.

Comment: Same principle. You can chain the parent method .parent().parenyt(), use .parents('someselector') etc. If you set up a new fiddle with what you have (I'm very lazy), I can show you.

Comment: Thanks Celos! New fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wwtSr/
You can see my attempt about halfway down:

$("ul.sub-menu li").closest("li.current_page_parent").addClass("highlightParent");

This highlights everything in the menu though, not just the parent. Also, it doesn't really work in jsFiddle. Nothing happens when you click a child link so don't know if that'll help?

Comment: Ah, from your question I assumed you were doing some AJAX magic, but I guess you are not :) If you have a <li> with the "current_page_parent" class, then why not use simply CSS and do a .current_page_parent > a {background-color: #whatever;}?

Comment: wow. I really overcomplicated that! Many thanks for the help Celos!!